# Couldn't estimate the gas when running Mist against ganache-cli

Tags: mist, ganache

I am running `ganache-cli` locally, then connecting Mist with `/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc http://localhost:8545`

Then, when I try to send from one test acccount to another in the Mist UI, I get the following error:

> It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, then it may consume all the gas you provide.

All accounts have ETH. I have the latest version of geth.

Simply running Mist without connecting to ganache works fine, but I'd like to use features of the Mist UI against the nice test setup offered by ganache, hence my current setup.